# how to change postgresql listening port in windows?

Tags: postgresql, port

How do i change the default listening port 5432 of postgresql to another number?

Another question,

What steps do i have do to allow remote r/w access to the database using python pyscopg2?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just change the setting in the file `postgresql.conf` (can be found in the `data` directory):

```
port = 5433             # (change requires restart)
```

Remote access can be given by changing [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), just add the ip-address. You also have to edit `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Comment: if i give need to give access to the clients in my subnet, i need to do something like this right --> my ip is 172.17.163.108 and my subnet mask is 255.255.128.0, so i should add in line like
host<tab>all<tab>all<tab>172.17.128.0/17<tab> trust right?

Comment: That's correct, and you also have to change the listen_addresses in postgresql.conf. I wouldn't use "trust", only md5. Passwords don't hurt.

Comment: that's strange, because i try accessing with another laptop, it says the server is not listening at the port. I should use the ip address as stated in the ipconfig correct? does the port number matters? i've set the port to 1683, but i open the port for tcp.. btw im using windows

Comment: hmm i got it. the school doesnt allow client to client wireless connections

Comment: I also had to restart the service under Task Manager

Comment: Not necessary, but it can also be useful to update the content of the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<VERSION>\scripts\runpsql.bat` file to use the right port, if you want the shortcut to `psql` suggest the right port. (Runnning Notepad as admin should be sufficient.)

Comment: It's been awhile since this was answered, but my issue with changing the port in 9.6 was that it wasn't looking in a folder inside `Program Files`, but `C:\PostgreSQL\data\pg96\postgresql.conf`. After updating that file and restarting via `services.msc`, it's now listening on the new port.