# Alternative to port 5432 for connecting two PostgreSQL Databases?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, tcp

We need to query and pull data from our client's remote PostgreSQL database and ultimately import it into a table in our MySQL database. Due to security concerns, our client is unwilling to open access via the default port 5432 so we can do this. We have considered possible setting up a PostgreSQL database on our end and trying to connect with that, but we don't know if that will give us any more flexibility.

The question is, is there an alternative port other than 5432 that we can have our client open up so we can access?

Comment: You can configure Postgresql to run on any port that you want.

Comment: Is the issue finding a port or that your client be unwilling to open _any_ port?

Comment: Hey! to me it seems that changing a port should be easy task and we could do local tunnelling as well

Comment: what OS ?..................see this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964307/how-to-change-postgresql-listening-port-in-windows

Comment: However, your client may have a (sensible) policy to not expose a database to the Internet, no matter what port it runs on. In that case, maybe you need a VPN or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure PostgreSQL server to accept connections from a specific IP + authentication, without changing default port. This normally should be done even for local connections.
2. Configure router/firewall to do port forwarding (i.e. firewall:port9999 --> postgresql_server_ip:port5432) + add source_ip as another layer of "security"